# Amazon S3 serving file only to app user in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, fetch, aws-sdk-js

I am building a social network in react-native / nodejs and using the S3 amazon service to handle the users personal photos (upload, serve)

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to serve those images, my question is how do I serve those uploaded images to only the application users and not the whole world ?

At first I tried to explicitly fetch the image myself, this allowed me to directly put the S3 credentials, but it doesn't seem practical.

Is there a way to make every GET call made by an app authorized to fetch from my bucket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @sergey I made it to what fits my needs the 'getSignedUrl' method.

Here is the code that worked for me :

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native';
const credentials = new AWS.Crendentials({ accessKeyId: '', secretAccessKey: ''})
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ credentials, signatureVersion: 'v4', region: ''});
// and there it is.
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', { Bucket: 'your bucket name', Key: 'the filename'}).
```

And now each time I loop through an array containing multiple references to my photos, during each loop I create for an item a single pre-signed url that I put in my  component.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is S3 signed URLs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Instead of fetching images, create unique signed URLs to this images (with a custom expiration time, say 1 week) and pass those to your application. This way you can close your S3 bucket to the world, but your application will be able to obtain the images with these private links.

Comment: I managed to make it work thanks a lot, one more question, since each time I loop through an array of users I create n times of signed url with 1 week, when I loop again I will re-do the process each time, how do I ensure that a the same link is used unless it is expired ? do I have to cache and verify its presence each time ?

Comment: Did you figure the part with caching? Your accepted answer seem to be still generating new URLs every time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new AWS Amplify library to accomplish this: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

There is an `Auth` for getting user credentials and establishing identities, both in an Authenticated and UnAuthenticated state, as well as a `Storage` component which has public and private access profiles.

Install via npm:

```
npm install --save aws-amplify-react-native
```

You will need to link the project if using Cognito User Pools:

```
react-native link amazon-cognito-identity-js
```

More info here: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/quick_start.md#react-native-development

Then pull in the modules:

```
import Amplify, {Auth, Storage} from 'aws-amplify-react-native'
Amplify.configure('your_config_file');
Storage.configure({level: 'private'});
Storage.get('myfile');
```